# How to correctly serialize non-uniform data arrays in Django using DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am developing an API with DRF to receive data from a customer and write it into a database. I cannot change the format of the data so I have to adapt the API to it. The data contains a product which itself contains several sub-components in an array called let's say components.

```
{
   "serial_number":"12345",
   "manufacturing_date":"2023-05-19",
   "components":[
      {
         "serial_number":"12345",
         "type": "component_a",
         "manufacturer":"asdf"
      },
      {
         "serial_number":"54321",
         "type": "component_b",
         "manufacturer":"fdsa"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I can create models which reflect this easily:

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True, 
        max_length=255,
        )
    
    manufacturing_date = models.DateField()


class Component(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="components",
    )
```

If the objects in "components" all have the same fields this can easily be serialized by adding e.g. a ComponentSerializer to the ProductSerializer with the many=True option.

BUT it is possible that the objects in the array are different from each other and should be serialized into different models according to their "type":

```
{
   "serial_number":"12345",
   "manufacturing_date":"2023-05-19",
   "components":[
      {
         "serial_number":"12345",
         "type": "component_a",
         "manufacturer":"asdf",
         "comp_a_specific": 100,

      },
      {
         "serial_number":"54321",
         "type": "component_b",
         "manufacturer":"fdsa"
      }
   ]
}
```

To achieve this I left out the "components" layer in the models and linked the components directly to the product for simplicity. (I do this because I don't know which relation in Django reflects a list with different objects. OneToOne relationships from component to product would end up in a dict not in a list.)

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True, 
        max_length=255,
        )
    
    manufacturing_date = models.DateField()


class ComponentA(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    comp_a_specific = models.BigIntegerField()


class ComponentB(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

The problem is a little bit now that in the receiving data there is this list "components" which does not exist on model level. My approach so far:

serializer.py

```
class ComponentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # This serializer contains all fields of all components to cover them all
    # to get through the validation of the ProductSerializer
    serial_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    manufacturer = serializers.CharField(max_length=17)
    component_a_specific = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)


class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    
    serial_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    manufacturing_date = serializers.DateField()
    
    components = ComponentSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        component_data: List = validated_data.pop("components")
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for component in component_data:
            if component["type"] == "component_a":
                ComponentA.objects.create(**component)
            elif....
        
        return product
```

Like this I try to include this "components" layer only in the serializer but not in the model. This kind of works but I had to adapt the view as well:

```
class ProductViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    
    
    def get_serializer_class(self):        
        if self.request.method == "GET":
            return SomeOtherSerializer
        elif self.request.method == "POST":
            return ProductSerializer
    
    
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        # after the creation if have to delete the field "components" as it actually     does not exist on the model, otherwise it throws an exception
        serializer.fields.pop("components")
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        print("headers: ", headers)
        
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,            headers=headers)
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach, especially with this very broad ProductSerializer, and I also don't know how to serialize it the other way round (for the GET request) that every product has a list of components.

So is there a better way to serialize a list of different (non-uniform) objects into specific models?

Comment: While possible using different model objects in the same list is often not a good idea, and two models that share the same data fields often is not either, since it overcomplicated database design.